# What is wrong with my brandywine tomato?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, tomatoes

Just when I told my husband I had a great year so far starting tomatoes indoors, I noticed my young brandywine tomato has some sort of disease and it's causing the leaves to have some brown spots and the stem has some white spots (see photos below). They are growing indoors, temp is around 68F and 16hrs of artificial light a day. I also take them outside to enjoy nature a bit when the weather is nice.

Any idea what's wrong with it and how I can fix it? I isolated this one and the other starts are fine. This is my only yellow brandywine tomato plant though

[image]

[image]

[image]